# Python/Pandas - Creating a HTML table

Tags: python, pandas

So I've been doing some basic code right now, following a tutorial, but I'm stuck on generating an actual table.

My code is:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
import sys 
import matplotlib 
df = pd.read_csv("TB_burden_countries_2018-03-06.csv")
df = df.set_index(['country'])
df2 = df.loc["United States of America","e_mort_num"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = df2, columns=["e_mort_num"])
print(df)
df.to_csv('example.csv')
df.to_csv('example.html')
```

And the output is:

```
                          e_mort_num
country                             
United States of America        1400
United States of America        1400
United States of America        1300
United States of America        1200
United States of America        1100
United States of America        1000
United States of America         990
United States of America         890
United States of America         900
United States of America         790
United States of America         800
United States of America         730
United States of America         670
United States of America         700
United States of America         620
United States of America         620
United States of America         610
```

However, when I look at the html file I create, it doesn't generate the table as above, but shown below:

```
country,e_mort_num United States of America,1400 United States of America,1400 United States of America,1300 United States of America,1200 United States of America,1100 United States of America,1000 United States of America,990 United States of America,890 United States of America,900 United States of America,790 United States of America,800 United States of America,730 United States of America,670 United States of America,700 United States of America,620 United States of America,620 United States of America,610
```

Any recommendations on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're calling df.to_csv twice. You need df.to_html to export as html.

Comment: Oh, that's very embarrassing. Thank you for that con, the small details went over my head.

Comment: JamesWu no worries, I totally understand getting code blindness after looking at the same file for long enough! Happens to me far too often.